# SQL data that have time in them not showing with my SELECT query

Tags: sql-server, winforms, select, datetimepicker

Right now I display all the queries for today's date using this query which shows what I want perfectly:

```
    string Query4 = "SELECT * FROM TblMalli WHERE DATEDIFF(day, TblMalli.Data_Shitjes , GETDATE()) = 0";
```

But when I use my DateTimePicker to SELECT queries in database that have TIME in datetime column I can't see any data that include time,my select query:

```
 string queryPerdgvHistoria = "select * from TblMalli where Data_Shitjes='" + dtpData.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "'";
```

My date in db is saved as this: **09/05/2017 10:57:16 AM**

[GIF showing the query in process,notice that when I re pick 8 May the datas with time don't get included.](https://i.imgur.com/Up8Tsae.gifv)

Comment: #1 - This can't be both mysql and SQL Server, please re-tag appropriately. #2, is your `DateTimePicker` passing both a date and a time, and does that date/time match at least one record in your database? #3, your second bit of code is wide open to a sql injection attack, so you'll need to fix that.

Comment: @alroc Fixed that thanks ! Yes it's passing time too but selecting data with time in DATETIME column is not showing any data , My value for DateTimePicker is on this format  **09/05/2017 10:46 AM**

Comment: @Nex you think that you're passing in a datetime which doesn't match the record that you're missing from the beginning of the gif. But it sure looks like you're passing in just a date. That you're getting everything else on that date indicates to me that your picker is only passing a date and NOT a time along with it. Look at the data on your table via SSMS - you'll find that the time component of all or most of the records  have 00:00:00 for the time in `Data_Shitjes` Debug your code and look at the value of `dtpData.Value.ToString()` directly.

Comment: @alroc Yes in the beginning I didn't include time (I forgot) but now I need to include it and my db looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/r4heIDO.png
When I use my datetimepicker to select data from database I only get the ones with 00:00:00 time